# Can Increase Storage on Existing Greenplum Data node(vm)

Tags: greenplum

Our greenplum storage usage is over 80%, we do not want to expand more nodes. Can we increasing Greenplum storage capacity on existing Greenplum nodes(nodes are VMs )? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have logical volumes, you can add vmdk, move segment data over, then symbolic link back to the original segment directory. 
1) Shutdown gpdb cluster
2) mount new vmdk drives
3) move /data/primary/segN to new mount points 
4) ln -s  /data/primary/segN
5) restart the cluster

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question.